# oracle database visual studio query builder

Tags: asp.net, database, oracle, visual-studio

So I have Visual Studio 2015 Professional, connected to an Oracle database successfully (I am able to get database table data to display in gridview). I am now trying to filter the gridview to allow for selection of specific data via dropdownlist. I have Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015 all installed. I build the SQL query via Querybuilder as this:

```
SELECT Val1, PRODUCT, ID, SPGRD, "Val2", "Val3", "Val4", "Val5", "Val6", "Val7", "ValA1", "ValA2", ValB1, ValB2 FROM DATABASENAME WHERE (SPGRD= :PARAM1)
```

I am getting

> ORA-01008: not all variables bound.

Some of the (redundant) data in the table I have excluded, but including all of the data does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the PARAM1 that is not passed in.
You have to pass the param "PARAM1" to the query as input parameter.

For example:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("PARAM1", "Param1Value");
```

Comment: So would I pass this in the GridView_SelectedIndexChanged? (declaring cmd as new OracleCommand). I've passed it there and am getting the same error.